# Preventing default on a checkbox doesn't prevent ng-model changing

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-model

Due to some animations, a visual glitch occurs if users toggle the state of a a checkbox too quickly.

To prevent this happening, I wanted to limit the frequency with which the state could be changed. I thought a neat way to do this would be a directive.

I've successfully made a directive that prevents `ng-click` triggering at more than a certain frequency, but have a specific issue with checkboxes.

Here's the directive code (coffeescript):

```
angular.directive 'pxnMaxClickFreq', ($timeout)->

  restrict: 'A'

  # Make sure our event binding runs before any other directive
  priority: -100

  link: (scope, element, attributes)->
    timer = false
    element.on 'click', (e)->
      if timer
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
      else
        timer = true
        $timeout( (-> timer = false), attributes.pxnMaxClickFreq )
```

And a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPizhQMcZT6HZ2B3rh9x?p=preview) that demonstrates my issue.

#### Summary

`ngModel` is being updated when the checkbox it is specified on is clicked **even when the default is prevented causing the checkbox never to be checked**. How can I avoid this?

Ideally I don't want to have to integrate with the `ngModelController` as I'd like to keep the directive as abstract as possible.

Comment: The plunker which you have added is blank. Please update it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I forgot to hit save. Try the new link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` directive is binding the events in pre linking phase.Because of which the stopPropagation is not working.

Handle your logic in pre linking instead of post linking.

Here is the updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/lrZYpeElxbc2TRJl3eff?p=preview